# what's wrong in my query?

Tags: sql

```
@tablen1 varchar(32),
@tablen2 varchar(32)
as
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @table1 varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @table2 varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @table3 varchar(MAX)
set @table1 = @tablen1
set @table2 = @tablen2
set @table3 = 'AB_Dispensing'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' +@table1+'.ATM_ID,'+@table1+'.LE,'+@table2+'.LE,'+@table3+'.Dispensed''
FROM    '+@table1+','+@table2+','+@table3+'

where '+@table1+'.atm_id = '+@table2+'.atm_id''''AND''' +@table3+'.ATM_ID = '+@table1+'.ATM_ID'
    EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

When i run this query like this :

```
exec AB_DIF _3_0_PM_14_MAY,_3_2_PM_14_MAY
```

I get this message

> Incorrect syntax near 'AB_Dispensing'.

Comment: Side-note: Always use explicit join

Comment: Have a look at the actual SQL string in `@sqlCommand`. Probably too many quotes.

Comment: `SELECT @sqlCommand` to see what you are running

Comment: Run, `SELECT @sqlCommand` before you run EXEC and check to make sure the string is ok.

Comment: Change the `WHERE` clause  conditions as: `where '+@table1+'.atm_id = '+@table2+'.atm_id AND ' +@table3+'.ATM_ID = '+@table1+'.ATM_ID'`

Comment: Which product? Correct tagging gives the quickest and best answers! And this is certainly not ANSI SQL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always handy to print your dynamic sql and check if its valid.

If you pass `'t1'` and `'t2'` as input to your code and print your `@SQLCommand` you get:

```
SELECT t1.ATM_ID,t1.LE,t2.LE,AB_Dispensing.Dispensed'
FROM    t1,t2,AB_Dispensing

where t1.atm_id = t2.atm_id''AND'AB_Dispensing.ATM_ID = t1.ATM_ID
```

Notice the `'` which is causing this SQL to be invalid. You need to remove unnecessary `'` used in `.Dispensed''` and `''''AND'''`

This is what your sql should be.

```
declare @tablen1 varchar(32) = 't1',
@tablen2 varchar(32) = 't2'

DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @table1 varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @table2 varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @table3 varchar(MAX)
set @table1 = @tablen1
set @table2 = @tablen2
set @table3 = 'AB_Dispensing'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' +@table1+'.ATM_ID,'+@table1+'.LE,'+@table2+'.LE,'+@table3+'.Dispensed
FROM    '+@table1+','+@table2+','+@table3+'

where '+@table1+'.atm_id = '+@table2+'.atm_id AND ' +@table3+'.ATM_ID = '+@table1+'.ATM_ID'
--print @SQlCommand
    EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```